# Product of complex numbers $m+in$ with $0 < m,n \leq N$

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, algebraic-number-theory, factorial

I am trying to look for a generalization of Stirling's formula to complex numbers.  In the integer case:

$$ \log n! = \sum_{k = 1}^n \log k \approx \int_1^n \log x \, dx = n \log n  - n$$

For the imaginary integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ there's no analogue of factorial, but we can ask for the product of numbers in a given rectangular region:

$$  (M+iN)!_{\mathbb{Z}[i]} = \prod_{0 < m \leq M;0 < n \leq N} (m+in)$$

Does this function already exist under a different name?  How do we estimate the phase and magnitude?

Comment: I'd rather generalize it by using a diagonal square with the two lower corners being $0$ and $m+ni$. Looks more beautiful to me and it's assiciated to how ideals work in the Gaussian integers.

Comment: @zardo if you can find Stirling approximation in that case then please write an answer

Comment: This is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116336/combinatorial-interpretation-of-i-choose-n-where-i2-1/116346#116346